# Angular2 and Express

Tags: node.js, express, angular2-routing

I am using Angular2 app with Express.

I have this url `/v2/tickets?filterId=321`. Upon reloading the page, the url gets changed to `/v2/tickets/?filterId=321`. This breaks my Angular2 routing.

In the chrome network calls, I see 301 being thrown.

This is my simple server configuration:

```
app.use('/v2', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist')));
app.use('/v2/*', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist')));
```

Any ideas, Why is this redirection happening and how can I prevent it ?

Comment: Why are you letting express interfere with angular at all? You should have a rest api instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redict occurs because the redict is the default in [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#redirect). You can disable it with `express.static('dir', { redirect: false })` but then /v2/tickets could not be found and returns 404. E.g. express-static has the same behavior.

Do you have a base set (like `<base href="/v2">`), and return the index.html for everything this isn't your api route like

```
app.get('/v2/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'))
})
```

because i don't know how this could work with the code you have posted.

Apart from that the redict would not be a problem if you would not use url params, because angular would remove the trailing slash automatically. If /v2/tickets/321 would also work, this would be the easiest solution with a better looking url.
If you need the url param and want to use express and serve-static, maybe it would be easier to add a trailing slash to your path in the routing.

Personaly i prefer to have a nginx for the static files, because it is faster, has better caching, more options, ... and forward all api requests to to node like

```
location /api {
  proxy_pass http://api;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Yes, base href is set to `/v2/`

Comment: For now , I have added  `app.get('/v2/tickets', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});`  . This seems to work

Comment: Ok, but then it should work, because the app.get will not redict and the serve-static will not be used for the index.html